# I get "undefined method ljust"; What's wrong with this Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, string

So I am learning from Chris Pine' online tutorial and I am stuck with this program. I am doing what I feel is just what was taught in the tutorial?

**This is the program**

```
toc = [[1, "Reflections"], [2, "Glasgow Roots"], [3, "Retirement U-turn"], [4, "A Fresh Start"], [5, "Beckham"]]

title =  "The table of contents of Sir Alex Ferguson' Biography"

toc.each do |x, y|
  lineWidth = 15
  puts title.center lineWidth
  puts x.ljust(lineWidth/2) + y.rjust(lineWidth/2)
end
```

**Error**

```
toc.rb:8:in `block in <main>': undefined method `ljust' for 1:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
from toc.rb:5:in `each'
from toc.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you notice that your code divides an odd number (15) by 2, which means your fields will be 7 characters wide, and your line will be 14 characters instead of the 15 you may have expected?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) or [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

```
puts '%-*s%*s' % [lineWidth/2, x, lineWidth/2, y]
```

or [`Kernel#printf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-printf)

```
printf "%-*s%*s\n", lineWidth/2, x, lineWidth/2, y
```

Comment: I like this, though the questioner should note that in order for this answer to behave identically to the ljust/rjust code in the question, he should omit the space from the format string, like this `'%-*s%*s'`

Comment: @dcorking, Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your `x` is of type `Fixnum` which doesn't have the `ljust` methods. You can fix it by casting it to `String` via the `to_s` method.

```
x.to_s.ljust(lineWidth/2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved it. Learned it.

Comment: If your question is solved, accept the answer, so it doesn't show up on the 'unanswered' list.

Comment: @dcorking, what's the rush, considering that a quick selection may discourage other, potentially interesting answers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - no rush - I was merely the first to respond to the questioner's comment of "Thanks. Solved it." as someone always does, to help the newcomers help us ;)